# Output doesn't appear in Input field but value exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am confused, I used jQuery to `$("#display").html(value)` toward my html input with id `="display"` but nothing appears in the html input.

However we can see the value in the element : `"32"` (see picture)

Any idea why the value doesn't appear?

I try to replace input by span and it works well.

image : [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83yFA.png)
thanks,

Thomas

Comment: Your picture is not showing

Comment: consider changing disabled to readonly. <input type="text" name="country" value="Norway" readonly>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot set the `innerHTML` value of an `input` element (which is what jQuery is doing when you use `$.html()`). Instead, you need to use `$.val()`.

Try using `$("#display").val(value)` instead.